# Use variable on event on datatypes JS

Tags: javascript, events

I have object as a data:

```
export const modules = {
    digger: {
        volume: 0,
        maxCapacity: 100,
        onTick: (state) => {
            if (volume < maxCapacity) {
                volume++;
            }
        }
    }, ....
}
```

How i should use these variables?

Comment: What do you want to do and what have you tried?

Comment: I tried use `this`, but I have error `Cannot read property 'volume' of undefined `. I want do different operations with these variables on this event

Comment: `this` will not work here, as it refers to the global scope. You can try using a constructor function or class instead.

Comment: I use these fields in export constant and want to update their values

Comment: Whether `this` works or not depends on how `onTick` is being called. See the duplicate. If that doesn't help, clarify how this is supposed to be used.

Comment: @deceze — It's an arrow function, so it doesn't matter how it is called.

Comment: @Quentin Woops, my bad. So the answer would be to make that a `function` first, and *then* it depends…

Comment: @deceze , I use `setInterval(tick, 1000)`
And I want do some operations by every tick

Comment: `setInterval(digger.onTick, 1000)`? Well then, read the duplicate. Make `onTick` a `function (state) { ... }` and `bind` it.